# set value of multidimensional json array to string in android using volley

Tags: android, arrays, json, loops, android-recyclerview

I am trying Expandable Recycler view using Volley and [thoughtbot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view) expandablerecyclerview. Please see my JSON Array below.

```
{
    "Ravi Shankar": [{
        "staffname": "Ravi Shankar",
        "taskname": "tesing1 task",
        "id": "1"
    }, {
        "staffname": "Ravi Shankar",
        "taskname": "testing 2 task",
        "id": "2"
    }, {
        "staffname": "Ravi Shankar",
        "taskname": "IMAGE TESTING",
        "id": "4"
    }, {
        "staffname": "Ravi Shankar",
        "taskname": "IMAGE NEW",
        "id": "5"
    }],
    "Ritesh": [{
        "staffname": "Ritesh",
        "taskname": "testing3 task",
        "id": "3"
    }]
}
```

This array was group by employee name. I need to get the group name as a string and child array in a loop.

I tried below code but it's not given as I expected.

```
for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        String tstaffname = jsonObject.has("staffname")?jsonObject.getString("staffname"):"";

                        String ttaskname = jsonObject.has("taskname")?jsonObject.getString("taskname"):"";
                        String tid = jsonObject.has("id")?jsonObject.getString("id"):"";

                        //addTasks(tstaffname,ttaskname);

                        Log.e("EmpName", ttaskname);

                        tasksNames.add(new TasksName(ttaskname));

                        StaffName staffName = new StaffName(tstaffname, tasksNames);
                        staffNames.add(staffName);
                    }
```

Please comment for any clarification.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use Retrofit for JSON parsing. Besides that I thing the JSON might be the problem. It's missing `[]` brackets as you expect an array of employees but receive an object.

Comment: can I get the first node of the object for this JSON? for example Ravi Shankar and Ritesh and then array in a loop

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html see this link help you

Comment: thank you for the link but it's not helpful to me. I want to get the first element of the object.